# Can Google Vision API extract the multiple language code for corresponding text in the image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vision, text-recognition

Can Google Vision API tell us what language does the text belong to in an image

For example, an image contains "Hello" in different languages like

https://pocketcultures.com/2008/10/30/say-hello-in-20-languages/

Would it be possible to get the language corresponding to the extracted text in an image

For multiple languages in the image, How it will be detected. 
Refer below example image contains four languages. Vision API detected all four languages.

**Question** 
How to identify the language for the particular text in the image *[Refer below image and response from vision api]*

[image]

**Attached response from vision API**

https://jsonbeautifier.org/?id=4876ed03d4754b868067f0f119347e40

Answer (score 2):

Updated: Vision API [response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNCO6.png) contains the [detected language code](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1p4beta1/AnnotateImageResponse#detectedlanguage) on the image.

Comment: So does Vision OCR tell the language or not?

Comment: @Christopher Updated question kindly looks into it. For multiple languages in an image. Cloud Vision API can extract the language code for corresponding text in the image.